# how to change the inittab file in /etc

Tags: raspberry-pi

am using raspberry pi 2B board.

am trying to change the inittab file to execute my own program after login. but it is not working. in which file have to change to execute my program as a first program.

Comment: wellcome to U&L, user program are run from `.profile` not from `inittab`. we need more detail to help you, Can you run program manualy after startup ? What is the program you want to run ?

Comment: i am accessing the raspberry pi board using ssh. 
when am login into board. it is running it`s default program. 
what is the default program is executed by raspberry-pi after login. in which file there wrote it?

i wrote one application.

instated of running the default program..my own application has to execute .

Answer (score 1):

After login `/etc/profile` is loaded and perform some actions, then it loads scripts present in `/etc/profile.d` .After that the `.profile` in the user home directory is loaded, that script is is used for action that are specific to the user.

Comment: thank u soo much. it is working fine.

how  can i identify the flow of execution of board?

is it same for all arm e based embedded board or different?.

do you have any documents or links to know the flow of execution.

thank you.

Comment: Sorry i'm not a specialist of ARM architecture. A "Raspberry Pi Architecture" request on a search engine will gives you lot of information on Raspberry and on ARM. There is also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139952/what-is-the-booting-process-for-arm